# Free and Open Source C compilers for PIC10 family of Microchip microcontrollers?

Tags: gratis, open-source, c, electronics, microcontroller

I am looking for Free, Libre, and Open Source Software (FLOSS) C compiler(s) for the PIC10FXXX family of microcontrollers (MCU). What I have found so far:

- [Small Device C Compiler (SDCC)](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/): As reported [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/sdcc/discussion/1864/thread/28a64c551d/?limit=25#3f20), there are some work in progress by Vangelis Rokas for PIC16 and PIC18 ([examples](https://github.com/diegoherranz/sdcc-examples)), but nothing for the PIC10 MCUs.
- [CPIK](http://pikdev.free.fr/download-cpik.php3): Only aims for PIC18 MCUs.
- John Favata ported smallC for PIC16C84, later adopted by Erasmo Brenes ([reference](https://www.microchip.com/forums/FindPost/483487)).
- [MediumC](http://panda.bg.univ.gda.pl/%7Ejanusz/software.html#mediumc) by Janusz J. Mlodzianowski, is a fork of John Favata C compiler, but it is not clear what MCUs it supports.
- [AnyC](http://anyc.sourceforge.net/) developed by Daniel Webb, which is not clear if and which PIC MCU it sup[ports, and it hasn't been updated since 2006!

I would appreciate it if you could help me know about any other attempts to have C compilers for PIC10 MCUs, especially on Linux.

**P.S.1.** This post is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185221/4999991), because it is about freemium C compilers for PIC16 MCUs.

**P.S.2.** More curated lists [here](http://www.gnupic.dds.nl/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/electronics/comments/ap6m45/curated_list_of_awesome_free_and_open_source/).

**P.S.3.** I had already asked a quite relevant question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/572887/124243), while ago.

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite sure you're out of luck.

1. For low-end PICs, Microchip use their proprietary compiler, xc8, which absolutely sucks (extremely bloaty code, virtually no optimization, not-quite standards compliant)
2. Microchip use some kind of unfree header files to keep things awkward in the FOSS world
3. PIC10 does not work that well with C, it's quite different from a PDP-11 (call stack limited to 2 levels among other problems)

I think if you want to target such a small chip, you'd be better off with a macro assembler than C.